# Chome border thickness issue on zoomed resolutions: 'border-width: *px' does not fully work

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, zooming

This is in reference to the well-known issue in Chrome where some table border lines appear too thick on a zoomed resolution (e.g. 125%) even though they should all be the same, `1px thin`. There are many threads on this: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68304288/1005607), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828326/consistent-css-border-width-with-zoom), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157915/how-to-make-sure-the-1px-border-always-show-up-regardless-how-much-the-user-zoom) etc. Only Chrome has this issue, other browsers are OK

The common workaround is to play with `border-width: 0.5px-1.5px` to find a "sweet spot" where the table borders become uniform.

But for me, I have 2 tables with 4 rows, and when I change `border-width` on a 125% resolution, the problem just jumps from one place to another. Below is what I'm experiencing. I just can't find any decimal value between 0 and 2 that would resolve the problem.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Windows Zoom Setting:
[image]

**One other note**. Changing `1px solid black` to `thin solid black` doesn't work either, contrary to what was written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912523/1005607) in 2018.

Comment: Check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71703247/14545160 and let me know if it helps.